# System administration of mining rig/s

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, business

Newbie question; is there anything helpful you guys could point me to related to sys administration of several mining rigs.. my venture with an 8 card mining rig is slowly becoming a farm :)

What I mean is, I own a mining rig for a week or so (which is now being administered by the guy who sold it to me), and now several people are asking me to place their rigs at my place (I have large and secure storage place and I'm thinking of placing solar panels). My question was related to what to expect in future; Do I need to spend a lot of time daily checking up everything and re-configuring stuff. Thank you! :)

Comment: While most people still measure mining power using hash/s, this guy measures them in entire rig/s... ;)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you want?

Comment: what i meant is that i own a mining rig  for a week or so( which is now being administered by the guy who sold it to me), and now several people are asking me to place their rigs at my place ( I have large and secure storage place and I'm thinking of placing solar panels ). My question was related to what to expect in future; Do I need to spend a lot of time daily checking up everything and re-configuring stuff. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try https://getminera.com , which will run as controller on your pi or other linux machine.